# Proving $\Delta E_4 $ is a simultaneous eigenfunction of weight 16 for $ SL(2, \mathbb Z)$

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

Let $\Gamma$ be the $SL(2, \mathbb Z)$ group, $M_k(\Gamma)$ the space of modular forms of weight $k$ and $S_k(\Gamma)$ the subspace of cusp forms.

It is known (for ex. Neal Koblitz's book "Introduction to Elliptic Curves", chapter III section 2) that we have
$$
S_k(\Gamma) = \Delta M_{k-12}(\Gamma)
$$
and $M_k(\Gamma) = \mathbb C E_k$ for $k = 4,6,8,10,14$. Therefore, we have for $k = 16$ that
$$
S_{16} = \mathbb C \Delta E_4.
$$
where
$$
\Delta = q \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-q^n)^24 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \tau(n) q^n
$$
is the discriminant and
$$
E_4 = 1 - \frac{2k}{B_k} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sigma_{k-1}(n)q^n
$$
is the 4-Eisenstein series.

An exercise from my Elliptic Curves course asks for a normalized simultaneous eigenform (for all Hecke operators) that generates $S_{16}(\Gamma)$.

What I've tried so far: showing that $\Delta E_4$ is a simultaneous eigenform explicitly so I can find the coefficient for $q$ and normalize it. I've been trying to use the fact that  simultaneous eigenforms of weight $k$ given by $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c(n) q^n$ satisfy
$$
c(m)c(n) = \sum_{d | (n,m)} d^{k-1} C\left(\frac{nm}{d}\right)
$$
but I'm honestly lost in calculations.

Is there any other way to do this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Each $T_m$ sends $S_{16}(SL_2(\Bbb{Z}))=\Bbb{C}\Delta E_4$ to itself so it is clear that $\Delta E_4$ is an eigenfunction of all the $T_m$.

Comment: I think it would be better to first show that $S_{16}$ is one-dimensional. Then, it immediately follows that any element of $S_{16}$ is an eigenform. This is the method used to prove that $\Delta$ is an eigenform!

Comment: Oooh yes i'm so dumb. Thank you very much. I knew I was missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each $T_m$ sends $S_{16}(SL_2(\Bbb{Z}))=\Bbb{C}\Delta E_4$ to itself so it is clear that $\Delta E_4$ is an eigenfunction of all the $T_m$.

When saying so it is implicit that we are using a few results:

- The construction of $E_4=r \sum_{a,b\ne 0,0} \frac1{(az+b)^4}$ which is in $M_4(SL_2(\Bbb{Z}))$
- We need the construction of $\Delta\in S_{12}(SL_2(\Bbb{Z}))$ as a $q$-product (with only one simple zero at $i\infty$) to get that any $f\in S_{16}(SL_2(\Bbb{Z}))$ is such that $f/\Delta\in M_4(SL_2(\Bbb{Z}))$.
- $M_4(SL_2(\Bbb{Z}))$ is automatically one-dimensional because otherwise there is some non-zero $g\in S_4(SL_2(\Bbb{Z}))$  so $g/\Delta \in M_{-8}(SL_2(\Bbb{Z}))$ and $E_4^2 g/\Delta $ is a non-constant everywhere holomorphic modular function which is impossible by the maximum modulus principle.

  Whence $ S_{16}(SL_2(\Bbb{Z}))=\Bbb{C}\Delta E_4$.
- That $T_m$ is a linear map $M_{16}(SL_2(\Bbb{Z}))\to M_{16}(SL_2(\Bbb{Z}))$ (which evidently maps the cusp forms to themselves)